# Create an event (IBAction) from a cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

After all my searching, I didn't find any specific informations/questions on that one : I want to ***link a whole Table View Cell*** (like if it was a button) ***to an IBAction*** (which, in my case, will perform a segue).

The thing is that I apparently ***can't Ctrl-Drag the Cell to my code*** to creat an event (since there is no category for that in my connections inspector, in the storyboard). This last point makes me fear that it isn't possible.

I managed to create a segue, directly from the Cell, to another view but it gets triggered everytime I touch the Cell. And I need to have a condition on that segue, which is why I have a segue from my Table View (containing the said Cell) to the Target View. I then created an IBAction which calls the segue (Table View to Target View).

**How do I link my Cell to that Segue?**

**PS**: I can edit my question for the code, but we only have the IBAction in my TableViewController (declared as Class on my Table View in the storyboard) and then the Segue which was created using the Storyboard.
My Table is static (as for now, it's for testing).

Comment: why you not use `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` ?

Comment: Okay this seems interesting and just what I need! I am going to try and use it for my segue.

Comment: +1 to counter the unexplained down vote.  The down voter probably thought, "gosh, the OP is lazy for not reading the docs".  How about some empathy for the OP's misunderstanding of IBAction, which is how, if you were new and successful with IB buttons, you'd think it's reasonable to proceed.

Comment: Yes, I am totally new and only starting to use Table views... thank you for empathy! (I am trying to figure out and reading the doc in order to use that method and succeed in performing my segue)

Comment: So, thank you for the hint, it was pretty easy and everything went just fine using @Waki pointed method!
I am quite unsure what to do with my question : sure, I should have been reading some more doc. But I would have been looking in the wrong direction for a long time! With Waki's hint, it took an hour only (not counting the time I took before I posted my question that I spent trying other stuff). If Waki is thinking about posting an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise, what should I do (as a new guy to SO)??

Comment: @Oinobares no problem, i added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: It sounds obvious to me know, but thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to achieve this, if you just wanted a segue you can do this without code

if not do it like [@waki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22665043/1880431)

**Cell To UIViewController:**

[image: From Cell To detail Controller]

Comment: Yes, I did this at first. But I need a condition on that segue. And with that method, my segue was triggered all the time (it seemed not to consider my _if_ at all). Maybe I did something wrong (I am using a static table).

Comment: Oh so if you have a condition then you would do the segue from controller to controller, then put the condition in the `didSelectedRow`

Comment: Okay, well it's pretty much what I have done now anyways after Waki's hint : I have a segue from View to View and when the Cell is selected (_didSelectRow..._) it calls an IBAction which performs the Segue and just before I perform the Segue (this happens in my IBAction method) I have my condition. (It works just fine according to my _few_ test as of now)

Comment: I can't give much of reward for it (since my actual reputation), but if I may ask you for it : is it normal behavior when the Segue goes from, in my case, the Cell to the Controller, that it is triggered all the time (meaning, no possibility to put a condition in there)?

Comment: @Oinobares thats the way to do it if you have a condition, if you did not then you would do the segue from cell to View. You're good

Comment: @Oinobares Thats okay, you should be able to upvote now ( I gave you few upvotes ;) but yes that is the normal behavior because you hard wire the segue, so it will ignore your code

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```